# PyTorch Module with attrs cannot get parameter list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, python-attrs

The attr's package somehow ruins pytorch's `parameter()` method for a module. I am wondering if anyone has any work-arounds or solutions, so that the two packages can seamlessly integrate?

If not, any advice on which github to post the issue to? My instinct would be to post this onto attr's github, but the stack trace is almost entirely relevant to pytorch's codebase.

```
Python 3.7.3
attrs== 19.1.0
torch==1.1.0.post2
torchvision==0.3.0
```

```py
import attr
import torch


class RegularModule(torch.nn.Module):
    pass

@attr.s
class AttrsModule(torch.nn.Module):
    pass


module = RegularModule()
print(list(module.parameters()))

module = AttrsModule()
print(list(module.parameters()))
```

The actual output is:

```
$python attrs_pytorch.py
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attrs_pytorch.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(list(module.parameters()))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bgg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 814, in parameters
    for name, param in self.named_parameters(recurse=recurse):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bgg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 840, in named_parameters
    for elem in gen:
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bgg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 784, in _named_members
    for module_prefix, module in modules:
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bgg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 975, in named_modules
    if self not in memo:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'AttrsModule'
```

The expected output is:

```
$python attrs_pytorch.py
[]
[]
```

Comment: why do you make empty classes?

Comment: Good question. The empty classes are just for a minimal example. They show that it's not any additional class methods that are creating the issue, but the packages themselves.

Comment: i guess there must be special __init__ there what calls super().init in the special way, maybe because of that. And yes, this is a design faliule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get it to work with one workaround and using `dataclasses` (which you should, as it's in standard Python library since `3.7` which you are apparently using). Though I think simple `__init__` is more readable. One could do something similar using `attrs` library (disabling hashing), I just prefer the solution using standard libraries if possible.

The reason (if you manage to handle hashing related errors) is that you are calling `torch.nn.Module.__init__()` which generates `_parameters` attribute and other framework-specific data.

First solving hashing with `dataclasses`:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(eq=False)
class AttrsModule(torch.nn.Module):
    pass
```

This solves `hashing` issues as, as stated by the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass), section about `hash` and `eq`:

> By default, dataclass() will not implicitly add a **hash**() method
>   unless it is safe to do so.

which is needed by PyTorch so the model can be used in C++ backed (correct me if I'm wrong), furthermore:

> If eq is false, **hash**() will be left untouched meaning the
>   **hash**() method of the superclass will be used (if the superclass is object, this means it will fall back to id-based hashing).

So you are fine using `torch.nn.Module` `__hash__` function (refer to documentation of dataclasses if any further errors arise).

This leaves you with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AttrsModule' object has no attribute '_parameters'
```

Because `torch.nn.Module` constructor is not called. Quick and dirty fix:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(eq=False)
class AttrsModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

`__post_init__` is a function called after `__init__` (who would of guessed), where you can initialize torch-specific parameters.

Still, I would advise **against** using those two modules together. For example, you are destroying PyTorch's `__repr__` using your code, so `repr=False` should be passed to the `dataclasses.dataclass` constructor, which gives this final code (obvious collisions between libraries eliminated I hope):

```
import dataclasses

import torch


class RegularModule(torch.nn.Module):
    pass


@dataclasses.dataclass(eq=False, repr=False)
class AttrsModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()


module = RegularModule()
print(list(module.parameters()))

module = AttrsModule()
print(list(module.parameters()))
```

For more on `attrs` please see [hynek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315014/10886420) answer and his blog post.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such a thorough and thoughtful reply! I did not know about `dataclasses`, and will definitely look into it!

Comment: What makes you say “This stdlib does the same and more as attrs.“? Dataclasses are a strict subset of attrs.

Comment: @hynek If so, could you edit my answer or add a comment to extend it? I'm not so familiar with `attrs`, so your input would be really useful, thanks. I have added link to your answer, will expand it if necessary.

Comment: Edited my answer to incorporate your comment, thanks for sharing, didn't want to spread FUD, soz.

Answer (score 1):

`attrs` has a chapter on hashability that also explains the pitfalls of hashing in Python: https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/hashing.html

You’ll have to decide what behavior is adequate for your concrete problem. For more general information check out https://hynek.me/articles/hashes-and-equality/ — turns out hashing is surprisingly tricky in Python.